# Multiple MySQL queries on one page (WordPress)

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am currently running the following query on my WordPress website:

PHP:

```
function get_details($key, $post_id)  { 
    global $wpdb;
    $values = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT meta_value FROM {$wpdb->prefix}new_post_meta WHERE meta_key = '{$key}' AND post_id = '{$post_id}' LIMIT 1" );
    return $values[0]->meta_value;
}
```

ON PAGE:

```
<?php echo get_details('facebook_url', $post_id); ?>
```

It is a new custom table which works in the same way as the WP posts meta.

This is run 20 + times on the page so I was wondering if there's a better way to do this?

Currently running the query direct in the database it takes 0.5128 sec and the database table is 36MB in size.

The query is really slowing the site down.

Comment: Pass the post ids as an array and use in() in the sql.

Comment: Sorry Shadow, they all use the same ID so by multiple queries I mean:

`<?php echo get_details('facebook_url', $post_id); ?>
<?php echo get_details('twitter_url', $post_id); ?>
<?php echo get_details('pinterest_url', $post_id); ?>`

etc.

Comment: Then pass the keys as an array and use in()

Comment: Ah OK yes makes sense, how would I use this as a class so for example

`function get_details() {
//stuff here
}
function get_facebook_url() {
   $this->get_details('facebook_url'); 
}`

HTML
`
<?php echo $details->get_facebook_url(); ?>`

Comment: Managed to get it working, thanks Shadow so simple I didn't even think of trying it!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to shadow for stating the obvious but it worked:

```
public function get_meta_data() {
    $meta_keys = array(
//META KEYS GO HERE IN ARRAY
    );
    $mks = implode("', '", $meta_keys);

    //Get Results
    global $wpdb;
    $results = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT meta_key, meta_value FROM {$wpdb->prefix}resorts_meta WHERE meta_key IN ('{$mks}') AND post_id = '{$this->id}'", OBJECT_K );

    foreach($results as $key => $value) {
      $this->$key = $value->meta_value;
    }

    return "SELECT meta_key, meta_value FROM {$wpdb->prefix}new_post_meta WHERE meta_key IN ('{$mks}') AND post_id = '{$this->id}'";
```

I then created a function to display the results in $this->variables like so:

`public function get_meta( $key ) {
    return $this->$key;
  }`

And then stored get_meta_data in the construct function.

Thanks Shadow.